# PTSD from death by knife

Tags: death, ptsd

Say you have someone who died due to their throat being cut with a knife. It was by someone they were familiar with, but not exactly a friend or someone they really trusted. They get resurrected with all their memories later, and would definitely have PTSD related to knives. As I have never been stabbed or killed, how would this PTSD manifest? (The character in life was an extrovert who used humor to deflect from problems)

Comment: I'm not sure we can answer. Many individuals respond differently to stress or a trauma. Even if they seem similar. I would suggest just seeking out some public trauma reports if they exist and try to match something that matches the character and is believable.

Comment: *"Would definitely have PTSD related to knives":* maybe they would, maybe the wouldn't. Depends on the person, doesn't it? (Which in the context of this site, means that it depends on the plot of the story.) Practical experience shows that only *some* wounded soldiers experience PTSD, and not-wounded soldiers engaged in combat *also* experience PTSD. (Even giving birth may result in PTSD in a small number of cases.) That's why it is called a "disorder" and it is not considered a regular expected response.

Comment: PTSD is not "related to" a weapon.  It's a condition that affects people in many ways and there's no reason to think your victim would have a particular reaction to a knife at all.  It's about loss of control (of life, of self, vulnerability).  I have complex PTSD myself.  It's unfortunate that people think PTSD relates to such specific things because that's not how it works and it's very frustrating to have people act on that expectation - e.g. "there are no knifes, why are you having a problem ?".

Comment: Please learn to use capitals when writing/typing.  It's not that difficult and my phone tends to capitalize automatically.  It helps readers scan text.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about building a fictional world.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the most likely symptoms of PTSD caused by being killed with a knife?

Comment: I think this one is going to be very hard, because it depends on so many things, least of all being the person.  However, if you really want to tease this one apart, I'd start with a key first question:  would ressurection in general leave someone with PTSD *in your world*?  It is generally accepted that death is a very traumatic experience.  How you want to handle that question would strongly shift how you handle the specifics of a given death.

Comment: Hi Ren!  I'd like to address a couple issues. First, I voted to close your query because a) it's a matter of idle curiosity and b) you are not asking a worldbuilding related question. Please check out our [tour], our [help] and [learn what WB is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) before asking questions. Lastly, it is considered very poor form to award the green checkmark within 48 hours of asking a question. Please be patient --- someone might have come along with a better answer!

Comment: On point A: we're not here to satisfy your idle curiosity. It took google a whopping 0.55 seconds to bring up half a million hits on knife related ptsd. On B: we're here to help you with issues or problems you're facing while making a fictional world. In order to help us answer your questions, we need to learn some context about your fictional world. You didn't provide that to us. You did a much better job with your merfolk calendar query!! That's the kind of question we handle here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PTSD is often about being trapped.

If they felt trapped and unable to escape then they're more likely to get ptsd.

So, while the stab wound wouldn't cause ptsd, most likely, bleeding to death might do it.

They could spend a long time holding a hand to their neck, trying to stem the bleeding, trying to escape but having no way to do it. No hope. The phones are gone, they can't reach the door, they're trapped in their apartment or wherever in an increasingly painful body.

That sort of immobilization tends to cause ptsd a lot more than when people feel they're making meaningful progress.

That was part of why WW1 was especially horrifying for many. For most of history battles were in recognized locations and would end. In WW1 people were trapped in small trenches with the executioner axe of shells slamming around them repeatedly with no meaningful escape or way to change the situation.

So, emphasize the trapped in nature of their death after the throat slash, and that will better sell PTSD.

Comment: Please don't answer idle curiosity questions that have no worldbuilding context.

Comment: @elemtilas You should not (IMO) be telling people not to answer questions - that's their choice not yours.  Maybe an exception would be if the question was e.g. an obvious troll or something, but this is not that case here.  Also the OP clearly is talking about a WB scenario (at least as much as most people do here) because they're talking about someone dying and being ressurected (doesn't normally happen IRL) and use the term "character" which clearly indicates intent.  So I feel your advice to this answer's poster was incorrect.  YMMV of course.

Comment: @StephenG -- While I appreciate you're opinion, I believe it's wrong. Part of the problem with answering bad questions is that a) this forum becomes riddles with answers to bad questions and b) the question can no longer be substantially edited because a major edit will very likely invalidate the answer. That leaves this forum with a bad question and a bad answer and no way to fix the problem. The respondent has been around on SE long enough to know that this was a bad choice. Lastly, as for it being the respondent's "choice", yes ...

Comment: @StephenG -- it is the respondent's "choice" whether or not to answer a bad question. Believe me, I've answered bad questions in my time! It is also our right and indeed a community obligation to "rebuke" others when they're doing something wrong. In other words, in this case, to remind folks that it's best to look carefully at a question before answering and ensure that it's a good question. This one is not. There is no worldbuilding context to speak of, no background of any kind, no criteria by which to judge the answers. All the problems that get complained about in Meta.

Comment: @StephenG -- As for the word choice, indeed *resurrexion* doesn't often happen in real life. Historically it's only happened once. I chalked that up to poor word choice. Resuscitate would work just as well in the context of a real world / idle curiosity type question.

Comment: @elemtilas We won't agree I think.  Your only stated objection to the question is that it's not worldbuilding which I have demonstrated to be a dubious claim.  You see black, I see white.  Regardless I consider it improper to complain to people answering - they're just trying to help the OP and it's not against the rules to answer a question **later** deemed off-topic - we can't apply rules or laws retrospectively and remain fair.

Comment: @StephenG -- Possibly not on this! There are two objections: there is no worldbuilding context (easily fixable) and  the question reads more like idle curiosity (also easily fixable). It's alright if we see things differently, for example I don't see that you demonstrated your claim. Just using the word "resurrect" doesn't mean the OP is talking about a fictional world. However, if the query is supposed to be about a fictional world, I'd be happy to VTR should they care to grace us with an appropriate edit!

Comment: @StephenG -- As for the appropriateness of reminding someone not to answer a bad question, I agree with you 100% that the respondent was trying to help! And also, it is not against the rules to answer a query that is **later** closed. My point is simply that the respondent, while within rights to answer, didn't really do either the querent or the community a great favour in doing so. As a community, we really need to pay more attention to the quality of the questions we answer. This could have been a great question if people would just lay off for moment, ask for clarifications, and

Comment: @StephenG --- (cont)... let the question be fixed before answering. No rules are being "applied retroactively"; the only rule I'm asking for people (myself included) to apply is the Rule of Common Sense. I think your concern here is a good one, and I also think it would be best to put all of this into a Meta discussion!

Comment: @elemtilas I have no idea how you expect us to know all the problems are fixed before answering.   Who's decides when it's "fixed" ?  That idea is unworkable.  Post that idea on Meta by all means if you want.  This question was closed in just 15 hours (you voted for that) so there's wasn't much of a window for the OP to fix the question.  Maybe you should have waited before VTCing, not complain about people answering.

Comment: @StephenG -- [I put the question on Meta.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8540/can-we-encourage-people-to-not-answer-questions-that-need-to-be-closed)  Please follow up there.